# Exit message on specific link off site

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, exit

I have found many options to create an exit message that pops up when a person tries to leave a site. I am trying to create an exit message that only appears when a person clicks on a specific link on one of my pages.

If someone leaves the site through any other method, no message would appear. I am new to javascript so specific instruction would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="http://example.com/"
    onClick="return confirm('You are about to leave the site.');">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you only need to attach the event handler to the one `a href` that you are targeting.

So something like this

```
<script>
   function leaveSite(){
      alert("You are leaving my site");
    }
</script>

<a href="" onclick="leaveSite()">Link</a>
```